Warning: Prop `href` did not match. Server: "/sign-in" Client: "/MedCard" at a LinkComponent
'use client'

import { HeaderProps } from './Header.props';
import cn from 'classnames';
import styles from './Header.module.css';
import LogoIcon from './logoHosp.svg';
import LoginIcon from './LoginIcon.svg';
import LogoutIcon from './LogoutIcon.svg';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import React from 'react';
import { Specialty } from '../../interfaces/specialization.interface';
import { eraseCookie, getCookie } from '../../utils/setCookie';
import { decodeJWTToken } from '../../utils/decodeJWT';


export const Header = ({ className, ...props }: HeaderProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [specialization, setSpecialization] = useState<Specialty[]>([])
    const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
    const [userLastName, setUserLastName] = useState<string>("");
    const router = useRouter();
    const isUserLoggedIn = !!getCookie("accessToken");


    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            setIsLogin(!!getCookie("accessToken"));
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [getCookie("accessToken")]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch data from the API
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/specialty/all")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data: Specialty[]) => {
                console.log('Received data:', data);
                setSpecialization(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));

        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const token = getCookie("accessToken");
            if (token) {
                const decodedToken = decodeJWTToken(token);
                setUserLastName(decodedToken.lastName);
            }
        }
    }, []);

    function logout(e: React.MouseEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const confirmed = window.confirm("Точно ли хотите выйти ?");
        if (confirmed) {
            eraseCookie("accessToken");
            console.log("Выход из аккаунта успешно выполнен!");
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                router.refresh();
            }
        }
    }


    return (
        <header className={cn(className, styles.header)} {...props}>
            <div className={styles.navbar}>
                <Link href='/'><LogoIcon className={styles.logo} /></Link>
                <ul className={styles.ul}>
                    <li className={styles.dropdownParent}>Врачи
                        <ul className={styles.dropdown}>
                            {specialization.map(special => (
                                <li key={special.id}><Link href={`/Doctorsss/${encodeURIComponent(special.name)}`}>
                                    <span>{special.name}</span>
                                </Link></li>))}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <Link href='/'><li>Услуги</li></Link>

                    {isUserLoggedIn ? (
                        <Link href="/MedCard">
                            <li>Мед. карта</li>
                        </Link>) : (
                        <Link href="/sign-in">
                            <li>Мед. карта</li>
                        </Link>
                    )}

                    <Link href='/About'><li>О нас</li></Link>
                </ul>
                <div className={styles.phoneNumbers}>
                    <p>8 (900) 589-52-17</p>
                    <p>8 (904) 599-87-15</p>
                    <p className={styles.freeCall}>Бесплатный звонок по России</p>
                </div>

                {!isLogin && (
                    <Link href="../sign-in/"><LoginIcon className={styles.login} placeholder="Войти" /> </Link>
                )}

                {isLogin && (
                    <div>
                        <Link href="/">
                            <LogoutIcon className={styles.logout} onClick={logout} placeholder="Выход" />
                        </Link>
                        <div>{userLastName}</div>
                    </div>
                )}

            </div>
        </header>
    );
};


Братцы, как исправить ошибку Warning: Prop href did not match. Server: "/sign-in" Client: "/MedCard", не пойму что именно не соответствует в href
P.S первый раз работаю с nextjs, поэтому был бы рад если бы сказали что именно не так в коде.
